# Are these SQL subqueries equivalent?

Tags: sql

I have this schema:

```
Hotel(hotelNo, hotelName, city)
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
Guest(guestNo, GuestName, GuestAddress)
```

I need to list all guests currently staying at the Grosvenor Hotel. This is what I came  up with:

```
SELECT * FROM Guest
WHERE guestNo IN
    (SELECT guestNo FROM Booking
     WHERE dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE AND
     dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE AND
     hotelNo =
         (SELECT hotelNo FROM Hotel
         WHERE hotelName = ‘Grosvenor Hotel’));
```

I then checked the answer sheet which provided an almost identical solution except rather than `IN` it used `=`. I.e.

```
SELECT * FROM Guest
WHERE guestNo =
    (SELECT gues....
```

Surely the `=` would cause a single value to be returned and since subquery would return a set of guestNo, the `IN`, should be correct? Is the answer provided incorrect or am I wrong?

Comment: The `in` should be correct for the reason you give, unless the `=` is followed by the keyword `ANY` or `SOME`.  By the way, the more natural way to write this query is with explicit joins.  I don't know why nested subqueries with such logic is how SQL sometimes gets taught.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nope it's 100% how it's given. I'll have to email my lecturer and warn him of the typo :). Regarding not using the join, unfortunately the questions specifically say without a join, but I agree, it would be more natural

Comment: Since there are only columns from Guest table in theselect-list I don't mind the outer IN at all. But in the sub-query I'd do a join, and write where CURRENT_DATE between dateFrom AND dateTo. (Makes no difference, just appealing somehow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality comparison `=` can be used when you are comparing one value to another one. However, if you want to check if a value is contained in a list of values or in a subquery, you *must* use `IN`.

---

One more thing: This can be more easily solved with proper relations, instead of nested queries:

```
select g.*
from Guest as g
    inner join booking as b on g.guestNo = b.guestNo
    inner join Hotel as h on b.hotelNo = h.hotelNo
where h.hotelName = 'Grosvenor Hotel'
  and dateFrom <= CURRENT_DATE
  and dateTo >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: Your first statement is simply false.  You can use `=` with a subquery.  It is called a scalar subquery and (in most databases) a scalar subquery can have only one column and at most one row.  Some databases support scalar subqueries with multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE var1 IN ('value1', 'value2')
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE var1 = 'value1' OR var1 = 'value2'
```

Comment: Your first query will give all guests matching conditions, while second query will return an error if there are more than one result in inner query.
And as @Barranka suggested, using JOIN is much more preferable in such cases.